# windows 10 - logitech mouse,keyboard detected only at bootup?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse

I have a Logitech wireless mouse, keyboard pair with USB receiver
(not the short "unified" one, but a bit longer one).
If I plug in the USB and reboot Windows, the USB receiver is detected
as "Logitech HID-compliant Cordless Mouse" and keybord  respectively
and both the peripherals work fine.

If I plug out the USB receiver (when I am leaving my desk) and then
come back and plug it in, it doesn't work! I will have to plug-in and
*reboot windows again* !!

Why does Windows seem to loose the information on USB removal!?
Do I have to make some entry in the registry ?

--

Comment: Are you sure the Receiver is the proper Logitech model?  I have used a Logitech Mouse with Logitech receiver on a laptop and unplugged the receiver to suspend, plug it back in after opening the lid and it all works.

Comment: Yes, this is a new one I purchased recently. I havent tried sleep and wakeup, but plug-out and plug-in doesnt work

Comment: I think you should replace the receiver with a different one.

Comment: Try the [Logitech Unifying Software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-au/articles/360025297913) to ensure that the correct drivers installed and the device is syncing properly.

Comment: This is the receiver that came in the box package, are you suggesting that I buy a different receiver and use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

> pair with USB receiver (not the short "unified" one, but a bit longer
> one)

Try a different and true Logitech Receiver.

I have here now:

Desktop with Logitech Keyboard, Mouse and Unified receiver. I unplugged the receiver (mouse, keyboard gone), plugged the receiver in and all is well. No restart, no logoff.

Laptop with both Logitech Mouse and Bluetooth Mouse. I do not use both together but I can insert the unified receiver and use the Logitech Mouse whenever. No restart required.

I have done the same at customers.

Try a new receiver and ensure it is compatible with your setup.

Further:  Try turning both Keyboard and Mouse OFF while the receiver is plugged in. Turn back ON.  Do the devices respond properly?  If so, the receiver remains suspect.

Comment: I don't have a on/off button on mouse or the keyboard. Do you mean - I disable the devices from Device Manager ?

Comment: I did not mean disable from Device Manager. The devices should manage more simply than that. Remove the battery, wait 10 seconds, replace the battery and see if the mouse works.